# TEMPUS DOMINUS datetimepicker parse from $_session

Tags: html, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I am tying to do this but it is not working .

```
value="<?php echo $_SESSION["end_date"]; ?>"
```

here

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.1.2/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="form-group float-left mr-2" style="margin-top:5px; width: 200px;">
  <div class="input-group date" data-target-input="nearest">
    <input type="text" id="end_date" name="end_date" value="" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#end_date" />
    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#end_date" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
      <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So this is NOT a PHP question. What does `<?php echo $_SESSION["end_date"]; ?>` render as?

Comment: I have updated the snippet I made with a date. Please change that date to the date given by your PHP

Comment: Getting a bootstrap error too on focus of the field